# Reformatting ListTile UI Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a shopping cart style list for adding and removing products from a total shopping basket and adding the cost. I want to have buttons indicating the quantity of items within the shopping basket, but I'm having problems with the UI. I want the product name and price to be aligned to the left and the counter to be aligned to the right of the tile

I've Tried Using a List Tile.

```
    ListTile(
          title:Text(record.name),
          subtitle: Text(record.sellingprice.toString()+" RMB"),
         trailing: 
     Row(mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.end,children: 
    <Widget>[
      new FloatingActionButton(
        mini: true,
        onPressed: add,
        child: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black,),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,),

      new Text('$_n',
          ),

      new FloatingActionButton(
        mini: true,
        onPressed: minus,
        child: new Icon(
            const IconData(0xe15b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
            color: Colors.black),

      ),]),
      onTap: () => totalCost + record.sellingprice,
    ),
```

But That just gives me what is shown in the image. Any idea how to fix?
[ListTile spacing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoswZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the row to use the minimum size.

Add this param to the row:

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```

Comment: Ok, that's solved the spacing problem, but now the text and the counter are all squashed together, is there a way to align the text to the left and the counter to the right? Thanks

Comment: Ok. Right. That's another issue that you can solve by adding some padding and wrapping the different widgets with the `Padding()` widget. Or you could add a `SizedBox(width: 10.0),` widget as the first child of the counter row. This adds some spacing.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for the help, also found out that you could use a mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, to achieve the same result.